# How to fix a Receiver in message expression is an uninitialized value warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, analyzer

I'm receiving the following error message for some code that creates a UIButton. How would I go about initialising this to fix this error that Analyzer warned me about:

**Logic error: Receiver in message expression is an uninitialized value**

the error occurs on the line in bold

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *textLabel;
    UILabel *detailTextLabel;
    UIButton *button;

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];
    UIFont *detailCellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8.0];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        // Initialize API title UILabel
        textLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        textLabel.tag = TITLE_TAG;
        textLabel.font = cellFont;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

        // Initialize API description UILabel
        detailTextLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        detailTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        detailTextLabel.tag = DESCRIPTION_TAG;
        detailTextLabel.font = detailCellFont;
        detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:detailTextLabel];

        // Initialize API button UIButton
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"]
                                    stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:9 topCapHeight:9]
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(apiButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    } else {
        textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TITLE_TAG];
        detailTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:DESCRIPTION_TAG];
        // For the button cannot search by tag since it is not constant
        // and is dynamically used figure out which button is clicked.
        // So instead we loop through subviews of the cell to find the button.
        for (UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                button = (UIButton *)subview;
            }
        }
    }

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    // The API title
    NSString *cellText = [[apiMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont
                            constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 2,
                                 (cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40),
                                 labelSize.height);
    textLabel.text = cellText;

    // The API description
    NSString *detailCellText = [[apiMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];
    CGSize detailLabelSize = [detailCellText sizeWithFont:detailCellFont
                                        constrainedToSize:constraintSize
                                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, (labelSize.height + 4),
                                       (cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40),
                                       detailLabelSize.height);
    detailTextLabel.text = detailCellText;


    // The API button
    CGFloat yButtonOffset = labelSize.height + detailLabelSize.height + 15;
    **button.frame = CGRectMake(20, yButtonOffset, (cell.contentView.frame.size.width-40), 44);**
    [button setTitle:[[apiMenuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"button"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Set the tag that will later identify the button that is clicked.
    button.tag = indexPath.row;


    return cell;
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize `button` and `cell`? (I assume `indexPath` is a parameter passed to your method, which most likely is `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)

Comment: the error occurs on the line in bold. thanks

Comment: I believe you can not make text bold in `code`. Mark it with a `// comment` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do something like this anywhere in your code?

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

(type might also be `UIButtonRoundRect`)

...or this:

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tell you that the button has noT been initialized.
Try change this line

```
UIButton *button;
```

To

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init]Autorelease];  //remove Autorelease if using ARC
```

Comment: thanks! and then [button release]; after the "return cell;" line? that won't release it too soon or anything?

Comment: My guess is the part with "isKindOfClass" wasn't finding any subview (button) and the variable remained uninitialized.